# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataUrl is not a function

Tags: javascript

I trying to resize an image and I am getting the uncaught TypeError message.

My code is:

```
var file =  canvas.toDataUrl("image/jpeg", 0.5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was being lame and missed that the function name was not toDataUrl but toDataURL.

So it should be written like:

```
var file =  canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
```